# Build and install Brew apps that are x86_64 instead of i386?

Tags: macos, homebrew, osx-lion

After I have done this:

> brew install git

I do this:

> which git

which returns:

> /usr/local/bin/git

I then do this:

> file /usr/local/bin/git

which returns:

> /usr/local/bin/git: Mach-O executable i386

I need brew to install as x86_64.

How can I force brew to build and install my apps as x86_64?

> brew --config

Returns this:

```
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9
HEAD: 1c64a6624ed83ef17af6e98638b8165400e9e908
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: quad-core 64-bit sandybridge
OS X: 10.7.4
Kernel Architecture: x86_64
Xcode: 4.3.2
GCC-4.0: N/A
GCC-4.2: N/A
LLVM: build 2336
Clang: 3.1 build 318
MacPorts or Fink? false
X11: /usr/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-357
Which Perl:   /usr/bin/perl
Which Python: /usr/bin/python
Which Ruby:   /Users/tdewell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
```

Update: adding brew --env

```
$ brew --env
CC: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CXX: /usr/bin/xcrun g++-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2

LD: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
```

Comment: Interesting. I just did a `brew install git` on a 10.7.3 install and came up with `/usr/local/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`. My config looks similar to yours (except for CPU and OS X version.. and I have an older version of Clang (3.0 build 211)). What does `brew --env` look like? Specifically your CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS?

Comment: brew --env   CC: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CXX: /usr/bin/xcrun g++-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/g++-4.2

LD: /usr/bin/xcrun gcc-4.2 => /Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2

CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=core2 -msse4
MAKEFLAGS: -j4

Comment: Hmm, mine's the same except for `-msee4` (mine is `-msee4.1`). This is a bit beyond my grasp. Though, it seems like it should be building 64bit binaries. Perhaps an installed dependency was installed as i386 causing git to build like that? Have you installed others and verified all brews are building that way? maybe try `brew install coreutils`?

Comment: I did a brew install postgres and that ended up as i386 also.

Comment: Brew is a bunch of ruby scripts, and if it's run by a 32-bit ruby, you'll probably get 32-bit builds of everything. And I notice you're using /Users/tdewell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby in place of /usr/bin/ruby. Is that by any chance a 32-bit build?

Comment: @abarnert the Ruby is 64 bit: $ file /Users/tdewell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
/Users/tdewell/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64

Comment: @tdewell: Well, then that probably isn't the problem… but just in case, can you temporarily move it out of the path, and brew install something that doesn't have any dependencies, and see if it makes a difference?

Comment: @abarnert I tried dong brew install git with the system ruby: which ruby  >> /usr/bin/ruby .... It still is being installed as i386.

Comment: OK, then it's a complete red herring, sorry—but it's good that we got that out of the way. Next I think you may need to post a complete build log somewhere so we can see whether brew is passing weird configure arguments, or setting ARCHS, or what.

Comment: @abarnert I created a gist of doing brew install at: https://gist.github.com/2885392

Comment: OK, brew isn't passing anything weird… is it possible there's something weird in your environment that's affecting gcc? Can you post the output of "set" somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been solved.

I installed Xcode 4.3.2 via the App Store and installed the Command Line Tools, but I had an existing Xcode 3.1 installed from years ago. I Googled around and found these commands:

```
sudo /Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools –mode=all

sudo xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

That cured my problem and after I did that the compilers changed for brew:

```
$ brew --env
CC: /usr/bin/clang
CXX: /usr/bin/clang++ => /usr/bin/clang
LD: /usr/bin/clang
CFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
CXXFLAGS: -Os -w -pipe -march=native -Qunused-arguments
MAKEFLAGS: -j4
```

brew installs are much better now:

```
$ which git
/usr/local/bin/git

$ file /usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Answer (score -2):

Try with

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: `xcode-select --install` adds command line developer tools. Perhaps you can explain how it helps OP build programs that are x86_64 instead of i386?