# Brew installing x86_64 (64-bit) versions on MAC OS X Mavericks

Tags: x86-64, homebrew, osx-mavericks

First of all, I know there are [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10921133/how-can-i-force-brew-to-build-and-install-apps-that-are-x86-64-instead-of-i386-o) but I'm having no luck, so decided to ask a new one myself.

I'm trying to brew install the 64-bit version pjsip, but I always end up with the i386 version.

I've seen people whose brew --env yields CFLAGS and CXXFLAGS, but for some reason, mine doesn't, so I have no clue where to set the correct architecture.

```
$ brew --env
HOMEBREW_CC: clang
HOMEBREW_CXX: clang++
MAKEFLAGS: -j2
CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /usr/local
CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH: /usr/include/libxml2:/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Headers
CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH: /System/Library/Frameworks/OpenGL.framework/Versions/Current/Libraries
PKG_CONFIG_LIBDIR: /usr/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/Library/ENV/pkgconfig/10.9
ACLOCAL_PATH: /usr/local/share/aclocal
PATH: /usr/local/Library/ENV/4.3:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin

$ brew --config
HOMEBREW_VERSION: 0.9.5
ORIGIN: https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew
HEAD: 8c19edbdd364200fb2cc9276b0bc49ec4cb98aae
HOMEBREW_PREFIX: /usr/local
HOMEBREW_CELLAR: /usr/local/Cellar
CPU: dual-core 64-bit penryn
OS X: 10.9-x86_64
Xcode: 5.0.1
CLT: 5.0.1.0.1.1382131676
GCC-4.0: build 5494
Clang: 5.0 build 500
X11: 2.7.4 => /opt/X11
System Ruby: 1.8.7-358
Perl: /usr/bin/perl
Python: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python => /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/python2.7
Ruby: /usr/bin/ruby => /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby
```

I've seen people referring to the version of ruby and I'm not sure it matters, but mine is a Universal build:

```
$ file /usr/bin/ruby 
/usr/bin/ruby: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture x86_64):    Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
/usr/bin/ruby (for architecture i386):  Mach-O executable i386
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`brew install -v pjsip` shows:

```
==> ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/pjsip/2.1
checking build system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking host system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
checking target system type... i386-apple-darwin13.0.0
```

Somehow it thinks that we're on a 64bit system, which is odd, as I'm definitely running a 64bit OS. Checking through the arch-host-OS detection code shows that is uses `arch` to determine the architecture. For some odd reason, this is reporting that we're a 32bit system:

```
$ arch
i386
```

While under linux:

```
$ arch
x86_64
```

The quick solution is to do a `brew edit pjsip`, and change line 22 to read:

```
    system "./configure", "--prefix=#{prefix}", "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0", "--target=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0", "--host=x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0"
```

then perform a `brew install pjsip`, and it looks like you have 64bit pjsip.

Probably fixable with an edit of the recipe to get the proper arch, rather than just passing in the `--build`, `--host` and `--target` options.

Comment: Mind you, it seems to only claim to be making 32bit binaries - the compiled files are all 64bit.

Comment: Thank you, it seems to have worked. I'm not sure it is "only claiming" to be making 32bit binaries though. I'm not an expert at understanding linkage problems but there were some (all) missing symbols when I was linking against the "32-bit" version binaries which went away now. Granted, it is possible that I was missing something before.

Comment: Well, I was wrong after all. The compiled files are apparently in 64bit. At least I was able to link them. I was probably just missing one of the many pjsip libs.