# How to compile Crypto++ cross platform on osx

Tags: c++, macos, homebrew, crypto++

My desktop application has dependency on the Crypto++ library. First I tried to install Crypto++ from Brew and link with my application. First error has arrived when I tried to run application to an older mac (with older cpu, which I suppose does not have AESNI instructions). it crashed with:

```
Crashed Thread:        56

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (SIGILL)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Illegal instruction: 4
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x4
Terminating Process:   exc handler [0]
```

After that I compiled crytpo++ with an older mac. so far all was good. but recently I encountered same error with even older cpu.

Basically the question is: is there a way to compile Crypto++ so the deployed lib would be cross platform ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ... the question is: is there a way to compile crypto++ so the deployed lib would be cross platform ?

Yes, but only within the processor family.

The problem is likely the use of a newer instruction, but not AES. There are three reasons I suspect it.

First, the makefile adds `-march=native` when building. This gets you all the CPU features for the machine you are building on.

Second, the newer instruction could be from SSE4, AVX or BMI because you compile on a newer Mac; while your older Mac can only handle, say, SSE4 in the case of a Core2 Duo.

Third, AES is guarded at runtime, so those particular machine instructions are not executed if the CPU lacks AESNI. However, other instructions the compiler may emit, like AVX or BMI, are not guarded.

---

Here's my OS X test environment:

- MacBook, early 2010

  - Intel Core2 Duo
  - OS X 10.9
  - SSE 4.1
- MacBook Pro, late 2012

  - Intel Core i7
  - OS X 10.8
  - SSE 4.1, SSE 4.2, AESNI, RDRAND, AVX

Based on the list above, if I compile on the MacBook Pro (SSE 4.1, SSE 4.2, AESNI, RDRAND, AVX) for the MacBook (SSE 4.1), then I need to limit the target machine to SSE 4.1. Otherwise, Clang is sure to emit instructions the older MacBook cannot handle.

To limit the target machine in Crypto++:

```
git clone https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp.git
cd cryptopp

export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -DDISABLE_NATIVE_ARCH=1 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1"
make -j 4
```

`-DDISABLE_NATIVE_ARCH` is a relatively new addition. I don't believe its in Crypto++ 5.6.5. You need Master for it, and it will be in the upcoming Crypto++ 6.0.

If you need to remove the makefile code that adds `-march=native`, then its not hard to find. Open [`GNUmakefile`](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/blob/master/GNUmakefile), and delete this block around line 200:

```
# BEGIN_NATIVE_ARCH
# Guard use of -march=native (or -m{32|64} on some platforms)
# Don't add anything if -march=XXX or -mtune=XXX is specified
ifeq ($(DISABLE_NATIVE_ARCH),0)
ifeq ($(findstring -march,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
ifeq ($(findstring -mtune,$(CXXFLAGS)),)
   ifeq ($(GCC42_OR_LATER)$(IS_NETBSD),10)
      CXXFLAGS += -march=native
   else ifneq ($(CLANG_COMPILER)$(INTEL_COMPILER),00)
      CXXFLAGS += -march=native
   else
     # GCC 3.3 and "unknown option -march="
     # Ubuntu GCC 4.1 compiler crash with -march=native
     # NetBSD GCC 4.8 compiler and "bad value (native) for -march= switch"
     # Sun compiler is handled below
     ifeq ($(SUN_COMPILER)$(IS_X64),01)
       CXXFLAGS += -m64
     else ifeq ($(SUN_COMPILER)$(IS_X86),01)
       CXXFLAGS += -m32
     endif # X86/X32/X64
   endif
endif  # -mtune
endif  # -march
endif  # DISABLE_NATIVE_ARCH
# END_NATIVE_ARCH
```

After that, you should be able to run your binary on both machines.

The GNUmakefile is kind of a monstrosity. There's a lot to it. We documented it at [GNUmakefile](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/GNUmakefile) on the Crypto++ wiki.

---

You can also limit the machine you are compiling for using `-mtune`. For example:

```
$ export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -mtune=core2"
$ make -j 3
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -mtune=core2 -fPIC -pipe -c cryptlib.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -mtune=core2 -fPIC -pipe -c cpu.cpp
g++ -DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -mtune=core2 -fPIC -pipe -c integer.cpp
...
```

---

> First I tried to install Crypto++ from Brew and link with my application...

I don't use Brew, so I don't know how to to set `CXXFLAGS` when using it. Hopefully one of the Homebrew folks will provide some information about it.

Maybe [Build and install Brew apps that are x86_64 instead of i386?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10921133/608639) and [Using Homebrew with alternate GCC](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9186033/608639) will help.

---

It is also possible you are compiling on an x86_64 machine, and then trying to run it on an i386 machine. If that is the case, then it likely won't work.

You may be able to build a fat library with the following, and it may work on both machines. Notice the addition of `-arch x86_64 -arch i386`.

```
export CXXFLAGS="-DNDEBUG -g2 -O2 -DDISABLE_NATIVE_ARCH=1 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 -msse2 -msse3 -mssse3 -msse4.1"
make -j 4
```

You might also be interested in [iOS (Command Line)](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/IOS_(Command_Line)) on the Crypto++ wiki. It goes into some detail about fat binaries in the context of iOS. The same concepts apply to OS X.

---

If you encounter a compile error for `-msse4.1` or `-msse4.2`, then you may need `-msse4_1` or `-msse4_2`. Different compilers accept (or expect) slightly different syntax.

---

For comparison using Linux, below is the difference in CPU capabilities between a Core2 Duo and a 3rd gen Core i5. Notice the Core i5 has SSE4.2 and AVX, while the Core2 Duo does not. AVX makes a heck of a difference, and compilers aggressively use the instruction set.

On OS X, you want to run `sysctl machdep.cpu.features`. I showed the one for my old MacBook from early 2010.

***Core i5***:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 58
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3230M CPU @ 2.60GHz
...
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca 
cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx rdtscp lm constant_tsc
rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid pni pclmulqdq ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 
sse4_2 x2apic popcnt aes xsave avx rdrand hypervisor lahf_lm
```

***Core2 Duo***:

```
$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
processor       : 0
vendor_id       : GenuineIntel
cpu family      : 6
model           : 23
model name      : Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU     T6500  @ 2.10GHz
...
flags           : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca
cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx lm
constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl aperfmperf pni dtes64
monitor ds_cpl est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 xsave lahf_lm dtherm
```

***Core Duo (MacBook)***:

```
$ sudo sysctl machdep.cpu.features
machdep.cpu.features: FPU VME DE PSE TSC MSR PAE MCE CX8 APIC SEP MTRR PGE
MCA CMOV PAT PSE36 CLFSH DS ACPI MMX FXSR SSE SSE2 SS HTT TM PBE SSE3 DTES64
MON DSCPL VMX SMX EST TM2 SSSE3 CX16 TPR PDCM SSE4.1
```

Comment: thanks for your time @jww and this long and descriptive answer, after compiling cryptopp with help of this answare i've got different linking errors, i'll come to this post leater after fixing link errors

Comment: @zapredelom - Well, its hard to say since there are no details. You should provided the details of the illegal instruction (which one?), and provide the details of your two machines. Regarding the link error, you should probably ask a new question since its different than this question.

Comment: thank you. I fixed all my issues and compiled tha way you suggested and it's worked. with one exception. the latest commit of cryptopp lib contained some link error , so I downloaded the official latest release

Comment: @zapredelom - *"... the latest commit of cryptopp lib contained some link error"* - Hard to say. Maybe changes for [C++17 and std::byte](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Std::byte)?